# Does Redis guarantee mget return order?

Tags: ruby, redis

Given this simplistic block:

```
mget object:1 object:2 object:3
```

Does redis guarantee that the return order will always be `[object:1,object:2,object:3]`?

I'm using the standard [ruby redis client](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb) (v3.3.0), so it should return exactly what redis does and not affect anything.

Answer (score 5):

Although the documentation isn't explicit about this, I think it does guarantee the order. It'd be a very useless command if it didn't.

Comment: I did some relatively informal scripting to check results and got the expected results back, but you're right about the documentation not being explicit about it, which is why I posted up here.

Comment: When in doubt, check the source. https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/d680eb6dbdf2d2030cb96edfb089be1e2a775ac1/src/t_string.c#L285-L301

Comment: Judging by the for loop in the source code I would say YES it ALWAYS comes back in the same order.

Answer (score -1):

As Redis Cluster is widely used, I have to make a note here that:

- `mget` does guarantee order in Redis Standalone mode like @Sergio's answer said

But in Redis Cluster, it's the client library that determines the order of the result. And apparently some of them do not make the guarantee, eg, [vert.x redis client](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-redis-client). From the [source code](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-redis-client/blob/329d78036afd2994e87af936d2265c905d19910a/src/main/java/io/vertx/redis/client/impl/RedisClusterClient.java):

```java
    addReducer(MGET, list -> {
      int total = 0;
      for (Response resp : list) {
        total += resp.size();
      }

      MultiType multi = MultiType.create(total, false);
      for (Response resp : list) {
        for (Response child : resp) {
          multi.add(child);
        }
      }

      return multi;
    });
```

We can see it simply merges `mget` result from every node and thus no guarantee on order is provided here.

Comment: I don't know why downvote